# Why is passenger not finding my rails root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, passenger, symlink, vhosts

I have a rails application that i need to be in a subdirectory of an existing application 
I am trying to deploy this rails application to a sub directory using the help of this [link](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) Here is my application [here](http://www.transprintusa.com/design/)  and as you can see i am getting this error (The directory "/srv/www/www.transprintusa.com" does not appear to be a valid Ruby on Rails application root)
. my public folder is here

```
/srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/design/design.transprintusa.com/releases/20110217203009/public/
```

or with the sym link

```
/srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/design/design.transprintusa.com/
```

here is my VHOST

```
<VirtualHost 184.106.111.142:80>
      ServerAdmin jom@jom.com
      ServerName transprintusa.com
      ServerAlias www.transprintusa.com
      DocumentRoot /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/
      ErrorLog /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/logs/error.log
      CustomLog /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/logs/access.log combined
        <Directory "/srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/">
                AllowOverride all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
 RailsBaseURI /design
    <Directory /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/design/design.transprintusa.com/releases/20110217203009/public/>
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I even ran this symlink command i ran also

```
  ln -s /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/design/design.transprintusa.com/releases/20110217203009/public/ /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/design
```

maybe i am missing something obvious and i just dont see it

Comment: The only difference I could spot between this and the [Passenger Example](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) was that you're using the full file path in the Directory definition after RailsBaseURI, while the example uses the symlink.  Maybe that's it?  And even if not, using the symlink will let you switch to a new release my retargeting the symlink, rather than editing your config files and restarting your server.  Cheers!

Comment: how would i do that ....i tried to run a few sym links and nthing...can you post an answer of ur suggested change to my vhost and the symlink command and ill accept your answer if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - followup on my comment.  I'd create the symlink like this (run it from "/srv/www/www.transprintusa.com"):

```
ln -Ts design/design.transprintusa.com/releases/20110217203009/public/ rails
```

That'll make a symlink called "rails" in your "/srv/www/www.transprintusa.com" directory (I'm not calling it "design", 'cause it looks like the design subdirectory already exists - that might have been part of your problem).

Then give that symlink as the RailsBaseURI:

```
RailsBaseURI /rails
<Directory /srv/www/www.transprintusa.com/rails>
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

And that's it - restart your server and see if it goes.  Hope that helps!

Comment: The T stands for "target."  It means that the first argument to ln is the thing you're linking to, and the second argument is the name of the link you're creating.  There are other ways to use ln as well, but ln -Ts is the only one that makes sense to me, so that's what I use.  Cheers!

Comment: the problem with this is i need the rails application to put up when the user visits transprintusa.com/design and not transprintusa.com/rails ...i can delete the design folder if i need to

Comment: Ah - gotcha.  In that case, do exactly what you said:  Delete (or move) the "design" folder, and make "design" the symlink.  I used "rails" instead because it looked like you were using the "design" folder to store your releases, and I didn't want to mess with that, but it looks like you'll need to.